# Where do I have to put actions when the game state changes

Tags: unreal-4

I’ve just started to learn Unreal Engine implementing a clone version of Atari’s Pong game.

I’m thinking about where to put the code to change the state of the game. I have an enum in the GameState class to manage when the game hasn’t started, or when we are playing the game. In case when someone scores I decided that I have to stop the ball and move it to its initial position.

My problem comes here because I don’t know where to put the code to do that: on GameMode class or on GameState class.

Where do I have to put that code?

Comment: It's related to networking. GameMode only exists in the server, GameState exists everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The GameMode is for storing the rules of the game.

GameState is for keeping track of the game statistics like score etc.  In a pong type game, it would also keep track of whose turn it is to serve next.

GameState is the better place for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why? I think what happens after some makes a score is a game rule.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand your answer. I have to start the game on GameMode, because it has the method `StartPlay`, which is not present on `GameState`, and then continue the logic of the game on `GameState`.